# Mapping a port in Xilinx Platform Studio and reading it in C

Tags: c, vhdl, xps, fpga, xilinx

I'm working in Xilinx Platform Studio, and what I essentially want to do, is have a VHDL module output some values, and then I would like to be able to read that value from another program written in C.

I figure what I want to do is map a specific port in my VHDL module to a spot in memory, and then read from that spot in memory in my C program.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how I would do this?

Comment: Is this VHDL code going onto an FPGA?  Where is the C program being executed?  On the same platform?  Or is this all in a simulator?

Comment: This is all going onto an FPGA.  C code and VHDL.  I'm using a Virtext-II Pro @Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand from your requirement is that you want to create a custom ip core(VHDL) and then add it as a part a XPS MicroBlaze/PowerPC system, where your core should be accessible by the processor(C programming).

Here you will have to use the Xilinx XPS EDK tools to do the following main steps:

1. First start with **Base System Builder** to create a processor based system. Select the necessary processor, peripheral and other components for your system.
2. Invoke **Create an Import Wizard** to create a Custom IPCore. This tool will take you through a features selection procedure for your custom core. Select 2-4 *Software Accessible Register* feature which are accessible by processor (C programming). Finally the Wizard will generate a set of files, including HDL sources, of an ipcore. The template sources can be found in *xps_prj/pcores/yourcore_v1_00_a*.
3. This is a big step. The generated HDL templates(*yourcore_v1_00_a/hdl/vhdl*) mainly contains a Bus Interface Unit (PLB/FSL) and an Example logic. Here you have to edit the HDL template sources to remove the Example Logic and instantiate your Custom Core Logic. You can divide the IO Ports of your core instance in to two sets. The first which includes IO ports to be accessible by processor(through C programming) should be connected to *Software Accessible Registers* in the HDL template. The second set of your core IO ports which you want to bring out of FPGA, necessary port mapping should be done to external port connection of the top module.

   Edit the PAO file(*yourcore_v1_00_a/data/yourcore_v1_00_a.pao*) and add your custom core sources in the order you want to synthesis it.

   After all the necessary changes is made in template files invoke **Create and Import Wizard** tool and Import all the Core changes to XPS environment.
4. Your custom ipcore will be seen in **IP Catalog** now. Add it as a part of your System and make the necessary Port Connection, Bus Interface and Address Generation for the Custom IPCore in the System.
5. Generate the Netlist and Bitstream of the system using **PlatGen**.
6. Create a C Application Project. Generate the Libraries using **LibGen** and compile the C application to generate the  *ELF* file.
7. Using **Data2Mem** tool merge Hardware Bitstream and Software ELF to *download.bit* file. Download the bitstream to the platform using **Impact** tool.

Ref: http://ecasp.ece.iit.edu/mbtutorial.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Is this a microblaze or power pc processor?  The simplest way would probably be a gpio peripheral.

http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/plb_gpio.pdf

If you need more speed you could use an FSL Link.

http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/plb2fsl_bridge.pdf

Other ideas and ways:

Block ram interface.
http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/plb_bram_if_cntlr.pdf

Write a custom plb peripheral.  Look for the "Create and Import Peripheral Wizard".

Answer (score 0):

FYI, this may be a good question for the Electrical Engineering stack-exchange as well.

My memory is a bit hazy on this topic and without more details on your design it's hard to make a suggestion, thus this explanation will be very high level.

I would implement your new VHDL module as a peripheral.

You may already know this, but the two broad topics/techniques to do this are Memory-mapped IO and Port-mapped IO. Port-mapped IO requires some new instructions to be introduced and a chip select line coming from the CPU to direct where this read/write operation will go to. The address space can be shared by both memory and peripherals. (Is the CPU part of your VHDL design?)

Possibly an easier way would be through memory-mapped IO.  This requires a hardware reserved address space and your new device will sit on the address & data bus listening for its address range. Your new module will need to adhere to all the timing and protocol requirements to talk on the bus.  In your C code, declare your variable as `volatile` and point it to the address where your device is for reading and writing.

Comment: I'm at that point, but I can't figure out how to get my VHDL code to write to that memory address.

Comment: @ZacAttack, What do you mean? Get the CPU to read and write to that memory address? Your VHDL device or "module" as you put it is only ever reading and writing to the bus (assuming memory mapped IO here). I'm afraid I can't do any better than this until you edit your question with a lot more info on what you already have to work with. There are some VHDL gurus on the electrical engineering stack exchange as well if it's a problem specifically with trying to figure out how to do something in VHDL: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/